# Print prime numbers in a range of given numbers

Tags: python-3.x, range, primes, control-flow

I'm trying to print all primes into a range of given numbers (low and max, given numbers included).

For example:

> num1=10, num2=20
>
> `>>> 11, 13, 17, 19`

My code fails in some occasions and I can't understand why:

```
num1 = int(input('First number is: '))
num2 = int(input('Second number is: '))
if num2 <= num1:
    num1,num2 = num2,num1
for i in range(num1, num2+1):
    for p in range(2,int(num2**0.5)+1):
        if i%p == 0:
            break
    else:
        print(i,' ',end = '')
print('\n')
```

Results:

> 1 to 7 >>> 1 3 5 7 (omits 2)
>
> 1 to 30 >>> 1 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 (omits 2,3,5)
>
> 1 to 60 >>> 1 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 (omits 2,3,5,7)
>
> 0 to 0 >>> 0 (prints 0 -> not a prime number)
>
> 0 to 7 >>> 1 3 5 7 (omits 2)

How can I correct this? Thanks a bunch!

ps. number 1 is not a prime too.

Comment: If num2 < num1, just swap the numbers instead of duplicating code.  Python can do a swap with `num1,num2 = num2,num1`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, I was looking for this. Thanks for the tip, I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake in your code was not having an `i` in the second part of the inner for loop range as opposed to `num2`

```
num1 = int(input('First number is: '))
num2 = int(input('Second number is: '))
if num2 > num1: 
    num1, num2 = num2, num1
for i in range(num1, num2+1):
    if i == 0 or i == 1: continue
    for p in range(2,int(i**0.5)+1):     # the second part should be int(i**0.5) + 1, not int(num2**0.5)+1
        if i%p == 0:    
            break       

    else:
        print(i,' ',end = '')
```

Also rather than having two branches for num1 < num2 and the other way around, you can do something like below. Further in terms of code design, it would be better to decompose this slightly into an `is_prime` method. That way, if you ever want to write a quicker primality tester, you could easily edit the helper function as opposed to messing with the main code.

```
def is_prime(num):
    if i == 1: return False
    for p in range(2,int(num**0.5)+1):
        if num % p == 0:
            return False
    return True

inp1 = int(input('First number is: '))
inp2 = int(input('Second number is: '))

num1 = min(inp1, inp2)
num2 = max(inp1, inp2)

for i in range(num1, num2+1):
    if is_prime(i):
        print(i,' ',end = '')

print('\n')
```

Comment: Some of your "corrections" are incorrect.  The `for`/`else` is not incorrect.  That is a valid construct in Python.  The `else` executes if the `for` completes, meaning the number was prime.  The break stops the `for` as soon as the number is found to be not prime...no reason to set `prime=False` and continue on checking.

Comment: @MarkTolonen That's wild. I had no idea. Thank you, I'll edit the answer. Clearly Ive been doing too much c++

Comment: FYI, `while`/`else` is valid as well.

Comment: Fixing `i` opposed to `num2` works, but still prints `0` or  `1`.

Comment: @YannisDran Look at my second solution as an example. It is hard to do this neatly if you don't decompose the work into helper functions. I have also edited the answer on your version to account for 0 and 1 but it is messy.

Comment: @gowrath you forgot adding this to second loop. Also, I edited my question to avoid repeating the same code as Mark Tolonen suggested. Edit your answer to accept is as a solution. Thank you very much!!

Comment: @YannisDran edited. The idea was for you to just look at the top half and ignore the bottom repeated code by just removing it.

Comment: @gowrath I know, I just wanted to vote for an answer that it may be useful for next newbies ;)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't consider the division of the number by the number itself into consideration. 
i.e. When range was 1 to 30, sqrt(30)+1 =  5+1 = 6, all nos below six had a case where they were divided by the number itself as 2%2,3%3 ... i%i.

Workaround would be to change the range of inner for loop as :

```
for i in range(num1, num2+1):
    for p in range(2,int(i**0.5)+1):   #Change num2 to i to avoid i%i
        if i%p == 0:
            break
    else:
        print(i,' ',end = '')
```

It is better to abstract the code like the one done by gowrath to avoid mistakes.